# Running K8s cluster after source code compilation

Tags: kubernetes, compilation, kubeadm

I am attempting to compile K8s source code from git hub and use freshly compiled binaries to deploy k8s cluster. i have 1 master (x215) + 1 minion node (x216) as my test cluster.

i have forked the main repo to my private repo on github and cloned it to x215

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxx/kubernetes
make quick realease
```

compilation was success as i don`t see any errors on logs i am getting at std out

now I figured that compiled binaries are in 
 `_output/release-stage/server/linux-amd64/kubernetes/server/bin`

How do i use these binaries to deploy K8s master services on x215 and minion services on x216 node.

*** Update :

1. I have tried installing K8s  by `yum install kubeadm kubelet kubectl` as shown on this link. https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-kubernetes-docker-cluster/  and it works... `kubectl get nodes` 
   `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` responses with proper answer on stdout
2. Now I have removed kube binaries by `yum remove kubeadm kubelet kubectl`
3. I have cloned https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes on x215 machine
4. `cd /usr/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/`
5. `make quick-release` did not got any errors on std out
6. `cp _output/release-stage/server/linux-amd64/kubernetes/server/bin/kubeadm /usr/bin/`
7. `cp _output/release-stage/server/linux-amd64/kubernetes/server/bin/kubectl /usr/bin/`
8. `cp _output/release-stage/server/linux-amd64/kubernetes/server/bin/kubelet /usr/bin/`
9. `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.xxx.xxx.xx --pod-network-cidr=10.xx.x.x/16` same command as ran during step 1; and it fails!!!!
10. screenshot of the error

[image]

**1. can you help on how to build binaries successfully using latest source code?**

I tried going over vast amount of blogs available online but could find help, i hope to get answer here

thanks

Comment: Try to specify kubernetes version:  

    `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.xxx.xxx.xx --pod-network-cidr=10.xx.x.x/16 --kubernetes-version=v1.14.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually i figured that the latest commit on the repo is not a good state to start with. when you do `yum install kubeadm kubectl kubelet`; the binaries you get are compiled from stable branch tag; which is same as binary versions.

i figured that yum install is getting me v1.14.0 version of binaries; now i checked out branch with same tag and that seem to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Follow the most popular kubernetes the hard way documentation

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/tree/master/docs

Everyone should go though those docs to get a fair understanding of kubernetes and its components like controller, etcd, api server, scheduler, kubelet, kube-proxy etc.